# Loaded image on canvas disappears when user draws on it

Tags: javascript, html, django, canvas

I am working with Django framework and I want to load on a canvas an image and then draw over it.

With the following code I successfully load the image:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input TYPE="button" onClick="myReload();" VALUE="Refresh">
<script>
    function myReload() {
        location.reload();
    }
 </script>
   {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<button type="submit">Upload</button>

</form>

{% if uploaded_file_url %}
<p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
{% endif %}

<canvas id="canvas" width="768" height="576" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3"></canvas>

  {% if name_of_file  %}
      <img id="image" style="display: none;" src="/static/{{ name_of_file }}">

  {% endif %}
```

I am trying to draw a polygon over the loaded image. When I press the 'Draw' button I can draw on the canvas but the image I uploaded disappears.

```
<button  onclick="drawPolygon()" name="plaque">Draw</button>
```

```
 function drawPolygon() {
     var img = new Image;
   img.onload= function() {
      document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor="crosshair";
      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    function reOffset(){
      var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      offsetX=BB.left;
      offsetY=BB.top;
    }
    var offsetX,offsetY;
    reOffset();
    window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

    context.lineWidth=2;
    context.strokeStyle='blue';

    var coordinates = [];
    var isDone=false;

    $('#done').click(function(){
      isDone=true;

    });

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      if(isDone || coordinates.length>10){return;}

      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      coordinates.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
     var stringY = document.getElementById('yA1').value;
      document.getElementById('yA1').value = stringY + ' ' +parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
       var stringX = document.getElementById('xA1').value;
      document.getElementById('xA1').value = stringX + ' ' +parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      drawPolygon();
    }

    function drawPolygon(){
      context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
      for(index=1; index<coordinates.length;index++) {
        context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);

      }
      context.closePath();
      context.stroke();

    }
    }
       img.src ="/static/{{ name_of_file }}" ;
 }
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the following line

```
context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
```

clearRect is used to reset a part of the canvas ([here is the mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect))

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks.

Comment: By removing the line the image doesn't disappear, but the polygon is not drawn correctly. For example, if you choose 4 points to draw a square, you can still see the line that connected  the first and the third point.

Comment: This is probably due to the order of your points in the `coordinates` array. closePath will connect the first point to the last. If you can provide a jsfiddle or codepen, i could have a look.

Comment: I now removed the for loop. It doesn't exactly work as before, but the job is done regardless. Thank you very much for your help!